# Adding a left const to an array of pointers

Tags: c++, constants

I work with multiple arrays at a time. There are functions which need to change
the arrays, others only need to read. Take for instance these functions:

```
// Only needs to read from the two arrays.
void f(int const *a[2]) { /* ... */ }

// Changes the two arrays.
void g(int *a[2]) { /* ... */ }
```

I would expect that I could call them both with a non-const array. Adding a
right-most `const` is always possible, a `const` on the left does change the
type. Still I would think that a `const` there would only make it stricter and
should be possible.

A data structure might look like this:

```
int *a[2] = {new int[10], new int[10]};
```

Calling `g` is not a problem, that compiles cleanly:

```
g(a);
```

However, when I try the same with `f`, it does not work:

```
f(a);
```

`g++`:

```
const_cast.cpp: In function 'int main(int, char**)':
const_cast.cpp:12:8: error: invalid conversion from 'int**' to 'const int**' [-fpermissive]
     f(a);
        ^
```

The message that `clang++` gives is slightly different:

```
const_cast.cpp:12:5: error: no matching function for call to 'f'
    f(a);
    ^
const_cast.cpp:4:6: note: candidate function not viable: no known conversion from 'int *[2]' to 'const int **' for 1st
      argument
void f(int const *a[2]) {}
     ^
```

Then I have tried to use a `const_cast` to force this conversion:

```
f(const_cast<int const(*)[2]>(a));
```

That does not work, because it changes the number of indirections as well.

```
const_cast.cpp:22:36: error: invalid const_cast from type 'int**' to type 'const int (*)[2]'
     f(const_cast<int const(*)[2]>(a));
                                    ^
```

I do not want to relax the requirement on `f`, though. It should be clear to
the user that this function will not alter the contents of the array. Also
there are other cases in the codebase that I do not want to change.

Creating a new variable with the right `const` does work, however:

```
int const *const_a[2] = {a[0], a[1]};
f(const_a);
```

Is there a simpler way to do this?

Comment: Use `std::array` if the size is known at compile time, or `std::vector` if the size is dynamic. In addition to all other advantages you gain, you *also* get a simpler declaration syntax where adding `const` at the right place is trivial.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`int const*` and `int*` are unrelated types, and you can't convert a pointer to the latter into a pointer to the former.

You can't do this because it wouldn't be safe, but the problem isn't that the function might modify the array, it's that it could replace the array with one that isn't modifiable.

Consider

```
int const constants[] = {1,2,3};

void f(int const** a)
{
    *a = constants; // OK, *a and &constants[0] are int const*.
}

int main() 
{
    int* x;
    f(&x);
    x[0] = 0; // Modifying a const object; undefined behaviour.
}
```

(Note that in function parameters, `T x[2]` is equivalent to `T x[]`and `T* x`.)

Comment: This also means that `void f(int const *const a[2])` is a proper solution as well. This prohibits the thing that you have demonstrated and it seems to compile as well. This does changes the function arguments, though I realized that it is not a problem because the `[2]` has been added by myself as well.