# Intel C++ cannot convert `T **` to `T const * const *`, GCC can

Tags: c++11, gcc, icc

## The Problem

#### Extension of Existing Code

I have a numerical library that has been designed with one “flavor” in mind.
Now I want to generalize this. The basic data structure is a “spinor” which
itself is a multi dimensional matrix. There are lots of functions which take
arrays of these spinors. The generalized functions need to take one such spinor
array for each flavor.

Say there is a function which, minimally, does the following:

```
void copy_spinor(Spinor *out, const Spinor *in) {
    std::cout << out << " " << in << "\n";
}
```

My generalization now is this:

```
void copy_spinor(Spinor *out[num_flav], const Spinor *const in[num_flav]) {
    std::cout << "Fwd: ";
    copy_spinor(out[0], in[0]);
}
```

In the real code, there is a loop over all `num_flav`, but that is not really
needed for this demonstration here.

As far as I understand, one has to read this as `const Spinor *(in[num_flav])`,
so `in` is a pointer to an array of probably `num_flav` elements (or another
quantity because `foo[]` is just `*foo` in a function parameter) of type
pointer-to-const-spinor.

The problem is that it does not compile when using a `Spinor *non_const[2]`
(without the `const`), see [my earlier
question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43027608/653152). From the answer there I
have learned that this must not compile because within the function
`copy_spinor`, the pointer `non_const[0]` could be made to point to some
`const` array of `Spinor *`. Then `non_const` would point to `const` data.
Therefore that does not work.

My conclusion was that adding *another* `const` will make it correct:

```
void copy_spinor(Spinor *out[num_flav], const Spinor *const in[num_flav]) {}
```

When I now pass my `non_const` as the second parameter, the function cannot
change `in[0]` to anything, because that pointer is now immutable. This has
served me well with GCC 6.3. Now going into production with Intel C++ 17, it
does not work any more.

The minimal working example is the following:

```
#include <cstdint>

typedef float Spinor[3][4][2][8];

template <uint8_t num_flav>
class Solver {
  public:
    void copy_spinor(Spinor *out, const Spinor *in) {
        std::cout << out << " " << in << "\n";
    }

    void copy_spinor(Spinor *out[num_flav], const Spinor *const in[num_flav]) {
        std::cout << "Fwd: ";
        copy_spinor(out[0], in[0]);
    }
};

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    Spinor *s1 = new Spinor[10];
    Spinor *s2 = new Spinor[10];

    Spinor *s1_a[1] = {s1};
    Spinor *s2_a[1] = {s2};

    Solver<1> s;

    s.copy_spinor(s2_a, s1_a);
}
```

On GCC, it apparently resolves to the second `copy_spinor` overload. The
variable `s1_a` which takes the role of the previous `non_const`, is allowed as
an argument.

#### Problems with Intel C++ 17

Intel C++ 17 however, does not accept that:

```
$ icpc -Wall -pedantic const-spinor-const.cpp  --std=c++11
const-spinor-const.cpp(23): error: no instance of overloaded function "Solver<num_flav>::copy_spinor [with num_flav=(uint8_t={unsigned char})'\001']" matches the argument list
            argument types are: (Spinor *[1], Spinor *[1])
            object type is: Solver<(uint8_t)'\001'>
      s.copy_spinor(s2_a, s1_a);
        ^
const-spinor-const.cpp(11): note: this candidate was rejected because arguments do not match
      void copy_spinor(Spinor *out[num_flav], const Spinor *const in[num_flav]) {}
           ^
const-spinor-const.cpp(10): note: this candidate was rejected because arguments do not match
      void copy_spinor(Spinor *out, const Spinor *in) {}
           ^
```

The error message is not particularly helpful because it does not say what
conversion was not allowed. It just seems that the `const` is the problem.

Is there perhaps something I miss with Intel C++? Is it lacking a feature or
did I make use of an unofficial GCC extension? Is that a bug in Intel C++ or
GCC?

*Update*: The example also compiles with current Clang.

#### Non-Template Class

The same issue also persists when the class `Solver` is not a template class.
Since `T a[2]` is the same as `T a[2]` and `T *a` in a function argument, I can
also just write the function like this, not needing the `uint8_t num_flav`:

```
void copy_spinor(Spinor *out[], const Spinor *const in[]) {
    std::cout << "Fwd: ";
    copy_spinor(out[0], in[0]);
}
```

The error is the same.

#### Free Functions

The same issue also happens for non-member non-friend non-template functions:

```
void free_spinor(Spinor *out, const Spinor *in) {
    std::cout << out << " " << in << "\n";
}

void free_spinor(Spinor *out[], const Spinor *const in[]) {
    std::cout << "Fwd: ";
    free_spinor(out[0], in[0]);
}
```

The error message is just the same:

```
$ icpc -Wall -pedantic const-spinor-const.cpp  --std=c++11
const-spinor-const.cpp(97): error: no instance of overloaded function "free_spinor" matches the argument list
            argument types are: (Spinor *[1], Spinor *[1])
      free_spinor(s2_a, s1_a);
      ^
const-spinor-const.cpp(30): note: this candidate was rejected because arguments do not match
  void free_spinor(Spinor *out[], const Spinor *const in[]) {
       ^
const-spinor-const.cpp(26): note: this candidate was rejected because arguments do not match
  void free_spinor(Spinor *out, const Spinor *in) {
       ^
```

## Solution Attempts

In order to run the code in production, I see the following options. None of
them are particularly attractive.

What would be a good way to go forward? I can alter my new functions all I
want, but I would like to avoid touching caller code as much as possible.

#### Const Wrappers

When I change the definition of `s1_a` in the `main` function to have the two
`const`, it compiles:

```
const Spinor *const s1_a[1] = {s1};
```

Then the function `copy_spinor` gets called with the correct argument type.

Every user of the generalized code has to write those `const`
wrappers for every single function call. That will get really messy.

#### Remove Const Correctness.

I can remove the left-most `const` from the function argument parameters. That
compiles cleanly on both compilers. However, I do want to document that I am
not changing anything in that array, therefore its values should be `const`.

A partial solution would be to use some preprocessor constant that removes the
`const` for the Intel Compiler only.

```
#ifdef __INTEL_COMPILER
#define ICPC_CONST
#else
#define ICPC_CONST const
#endif
```

Perhaps a user has defined some spinor as const. Then I am stuck and need to
have the const there in place:

```
const Spinor *s3_a[1] = {s3};

s.copy_spinor(s2_a, s3_a);
```

It should be easier to add a `const` than to remove it, so this solution is
pretty lacking. Also the upstream author would likely reject my changes due to
the changes in his code.

#### Add a non-const Overload for each Function

Adding an overload for each function would be possible. I have two variants of
the generalized function, the second one gets enabled when I work with the
Intel compiler:

```
void copy_spinor(Spinor *out, const Spinor *in) {
    std::cout << out << " " << in << "\n";
}

void copy_spinor(Spinor *out[num_flav], const Spinor *const in[num_flav]) {
    std::cout << "Fwd: ";
    copy_spinor(out[0], in[0]);
}

#ifdef __INTEL_COMPILER
void copy_spinor(Spinor *out[num_flav], Spinor *const in[num_flav]) {
    std::cout << "Fwd2: ";
    copy_spinor(out[0], in[0]);
}
#endif
```

That works well, there is just some duplication of code. Since my added
functions just re-use the existing functions, it is not *that much* code
duplication. Still a violation of the DRY principle.

Another disadvantage is that the number of overloads is `2^N` where N is the
number of parameters that are a `const *`. There are functions taking up to
three arguments like this, therefore I would need eight copies.

#### Let the Template Deduce the Constness

Abstracting `const Spinor` and `Spinor` away is possible with templates. I
could write the function as a template such that `S` can be either data type.
Using a `static_assert` will give a slightly more informative error message.

```
template <typename S>
void copy_spinor(Spinor *out[num_flav], S *const in[num_flav]) {
    static_assert(std::is_same<Spinor, S>::value ||
                      std::is_same<const Spinor, S>::value,
                  "Template parameter must be `const Spinor` or `Spinor`.");

    std::cout << "Fwd: ";
    copy_spinor(out[0], in[0]);
}
```

Ideally, I would like to specify that `S` can only be a `Spinor` or `const
Spinor`. Perhaps that is possible with C++14 and beyond, I have to stick with
C++11.

This solution looks pretty clean, I can add a template argument and an assert
for each argument in the function. This will scale pretty good and there is no
code duplication. The only downside could be longer compilation time (already
rather long, but not really important) and less useful error messages
(hopefully covered with the `static_assert`).

The error message when calling it with `int **` is the following for GCC:

```
const-spinor-const.cpp: In instantiation of 'void Solver<num_flav>::t_copy_spinor(float (**)[3][4][2][8], S* const*) [with S = int; unsigned char num_flav = 1u; Spinor = float [3][4][2][8]]':
const-spinor-const.cpp:86:36:   required from here
const-spinor-const.cpp:40:9: error: static assertion failed: Template parameter must be `const Spinor` or `Spinor`.
         static_assert(std::is_same<Spinor, S>::value ||
         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
const-spinor-const.cpp:45:20: error: no matching function for call to 'Solver<1u>::copy_spinor(float (*&)[3][4][2][8], int* const&)'
         copy_spinor(out[0], in[0]);
         ~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
const-spinor-const.cpp:29:10: note: candidate: void Solver<num_flav>::copy_spinor(float (*)[3][4][2][8], const float (*)[3][4][2][8]) [with unsigned char num_flav = 1u; Spinor = float [3][4][2][8]]
     void copy_spinor(Spinor *out, const Spinor *in) {
          ^~~~~~~~~~~
const-spinor-const.cpp:29:10: note:   no known conversion for argument 2 from 'int* const' to 'const float (*)[3][4][2][8]'
const-spinor-const.cpp:33:10: note: candidate: void Solver<num_flav>::copy_spinor(float (**)[3][4][2][8], const float (* const*)[3][4][2][8]) [with unsigned char num_flav = 1u; Spinor = float [3][4][2][8]]
     void copy_spinor(Spinor *out[num_flav], const Spinor *const in[num_flav]) {
          ^~~~~~~~~~~
const-spinor-const.cpp:33:10: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from 'float (*)[3][4][2][8]' to 'float (**)[3][4][2][8]'
```

In the comments it was pointed out to use `enable_if`. With that, my function
looks like the following:

```
template <typename S>
typename std::enable_if<std::is_same<const Spinor, const S>::value,
                        void>::type
t2_copy_spinor(Spinor *out[num_flav], S *const in[num_flav]) {
    std::cout << "Fwd: " << typeid(S).name() << " " << typeName<S>() << " ";
    copy_spinor(out[0], in[0]);
}
```

This is shorter, and perhaps more succint. The error message does not contain
my hand-written message any more , though. At least the error does not occur
*within* the function `copy_spinor` but at the calling site, so the user knows
where it went wrong. That is perhaps better. And the `enable_if` somewhat
explains itself, at least to more experienced template users.

```
const-spinor-const.cpp: In function 'int main(int, char**)':
const-spinor-const.cpp:86:37: error: no matching function for call to 'Solver<1u>::t2_copy_spinor(float (* [1])[3][4][2][8], int* [2])'
     s.t2_copy_spinor(s2_a, int_array);
                                     ^
const-spinor-const.cpp:51:5: note: candidate: template<class S> typename std::enable_if<std::is_same<const float [3][4][2][8], const S>::value, void>::type Solver<num_flav>::t2_copy_spinor(float (**)[3][4][2][8], S* const*) [with S = S; unsigned char num_flav = 1u]
     t2_copy_spinor(Spinor *out[num_flav], S *const in[num_flav]) {
     ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~
const-spinor-const.cpp:51:5: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
const-spinor-const.cpp: In substitution of 'template<class S> typename std::enable_if<std::is_same<const float [3][4][2][8], const S>::value, void>::type Solver<num_flav>::t2_copy_spinor(float (**)[3][4][2][8], S* const*) [with S = int]':
const-spinor-const.cpp:86:37:   required from here
const-spinor-const.cpp:51:5: error: no type named 'type' in 'struct std::enable_if<false, void>'
```

The `enable_if` solution looks better than the `static_assert` variant.

Comment: For your template-based workaround, perhaps `enable_if<is_same<const Spinor, const S>::value>`

Comment: Yes, that is great! Now the error message shows the user the calling site and not where it goes wrong inside `copy_spinor`. I have updated the question to reflect this.

Comment: Is the compiler bug the same without templates involved?  (`Spinor *out[num_flav]` is equivalent to `Spinor *out[]` anyway, as a function parameter)

Comment: @M.M: Yes, when I remove the `template <uint8_t num_flav>` in front of `class Solver` and change all `Spinor *out[num_flav]` to `Spinor *out[]`, I get the same error message from `icpc`.

Comment: ok, and is it also the same for free functions (as opposed to class member functions)?

Comment: @M.M: Yes, the same issue persists. I have updated the question in the middle. So I'd say that neither templates nor member functions are part of the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

GCC and clang are right here, Intel C++ is wrong.

The relevant portion of the Standard is **Qualification conversions** `[conv.qual]` (the section number may be either 4.4 or 4.5).  The wording has changed between C++11 and C++1z (to become C++17)... but your code which adds `const` at multiple levels starting with the shallowest, is allowed in all versions (C++03, 11, 14, 1z).

One change of note is that the multi-level const rule now applies to arrays of pointers, where formerly it only applied to multiple pointers.  But we actually are dealing with a multiple pointer, because the array syntax, when found in a parameter declaration, has pointer semantics.

Still, it might be worthwhile to try

```
void copy_spinor(Spinor **out, const Spinor *const *in)
```

in case the compiler got confused / failed to adjust array types to pointer types within a function parameter list before applying the rule.

Comment: I have just tried the pure pointer syntax, that does not seem to change anything. Using an explicit cast, `free_spinor(s2_a, const_cast<Spinor const *const *>(s1_a));`, works with `icpc`. However, that would litter all the code with those casts. Until I hear something from Intel, I will stick with the template solution because it makes the client code work as expected.